# Resampling pandas dataframe to a day is removing the hour part

Tags: python, date, pandas, timestamp, resampling

I'm trying to insert a large dataset with minute based data into Google BigQuery but to lower my resource usage when querying I resample the data into 4 separate csv files using pandas: minute, 15-minute, hour and day. For the first 3 everything resamples just fine. But when I try to resample to day values the resample function drops the hour info (which I just need to have at 00:00).

And BigQuery specifies a timestamp format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, but I only have YYYY-MM-DD for the day values.

Here's the code:

```
for i, f in enumerate(fluksos):
print "Flukso {} of {}".format(i+1, len(fluksos))
for j, s in enumerate(f.sensors):
    print "Sensor {} of {}".format(j+1, len(f.sensors))
    for week in weekindex:
        print "week {}, fetching data".format(week),
        ts = dl.tmpo_series(s.sensor_id, head=week, tail= week + pd.Timedelta(days=7))
        if ts is None:
            print "No data"
            continue
        print "success"
        ts = pd.concat([ts], axis=1)
        ts.columns = ['consumption']

        ts = ts.resample('d', how='mean')
        ts['meterID'] = s.sensor_id

        for group in ts.groupby(ts.index.day):
            filename = "day.{}.{}.csv".format(s.sensor_id,group[1].first_valid_index().date())

            #save file locally
            group[1].to_csv('temp.csv', header=False)

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_to_data,filename)) and (filecmp.cmp('temp.csv', os.path.join(path_to_data, filename))):
                print "file already exists, not saving",
                continue
            else:
                print "saving new file",
            group[1].to_csv(os.path.join(path_to_data, filename), header=False)

            print ".",
        print "week done"
```

I know I have to change something in the `ts = ts.resample('d', how='mean')` line but I can't seem to figure out what. Bear in mind that I don't have a lot of experience in Python programming.

EDIT & FIX:

I was able to fix the problem like this:

```
ts = ts.tz_localize('UTC')
ts = ts.tz_convert('Europe/Brussels')
ts = ts.resample('d', how='mean')
```

Apparently my Dataframes contained timestamps without timezone information and thus the hour part of the timestamp was dropped. So by adding the timezone before resampling the problem was fixed

Comment: General comment for people who come here from search. Sometimes it helps to swap `1D` for `24H`. That change alone may not solve this question, but it has helped me solve a couple of things with resample when I was using frequency >= `1D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem like this:

```
ts = ts.tz_localize('UTC')
ts = ts.tz_convert('Europe/Brussels')
ts = ts.resample('d', how='mean')
```

Apparently my Dataframes contained timestamps without timezone information and thus the hour part of the timestamp was dropped. So by adding the timezone before resampling the problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are losing your time, or does it just not display?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=pd.date_range('2016-1-1 23:00', freq='H', periods=5))

df2 = df.resample('d')
>>> df2 
              A
2016-01-01  1.0
2016-01-02  3.5

# Pandas 0.17.1
>>> df2.index[0]
Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D')
```

If your really just have days, you could also do this:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index + ' 00:00:00')
```